# myArray.push(["dog", 3]); should push dog and 3 to the end but does not, what am I missing here?

Tags: javascript

```
var ourArray = ["Stimpson", "J", ["cat"]];

ourArray.pop(); // ourArray now equals ["Stimpson", "J"]

ourArray.push(["happy", "joy"]); // ourArray now equals ["Stimpson", "J", ["happy", "joy"]]

var myArray = ["John", 23, ["cat", 2]];

myArray.pop();

// Only change code below this line.

 *myArray.push(["dog", 3]);* 

// Only change code above this line.

(function(z){return 'myArray = ' + JSON.stringify(z);})(myArray);
```

Comment: After removing the two `*` the code should work. So what exactly isn't working? Any errors in the console (-> F12)?

Comment: `Array.prototype.push.apply( myArray, ["dog", 3])`

Answer (score 2):

Array.push will push anything onto the array, what you are doing is pushing another array into the array, you will need to push "dog" and 3 without the array.

Array.push can take multiple arguments. So just do `myArray.push("dog", 3);`

Comment: Why you think it should be `.push("dog"); .push(3)` instead of `.push(["dog", 3])`? The example already pushes an array with two entries onto `ourArray`. And `myArray` contains a similar entry: `["cat", 2]`

Comment: Because that is how the question is worded. I saw the cat part, but that is not what they asked. Also there is nothing wrong with `myArray.push(["dog", 3])` so if they state it isn't doing what they expect, then that also co-insides with the question.